# Bash: Why is my read command not ending after pressing return?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, sh

I have a bash script that I need to run when I'm building and running a docker container. When I run the script independently, it runs fine. The read command ends after I hit return. However, when I put in the docker run command to run the script through docker, the read command never ends even after I press return multiple times.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter = IP Address: "  ip
export Ip=$ip
```

Here are the contents of my Dockerfile

```
FROM mono:5.20
RUN mono --version
ADD ./game-logic-csharp /gl
RUN msbuild /gl/sol.sln
EXPOSE 80
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/gl/startup.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/gl/startup.sh"]
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm4FD.png)

The read command should end after I press return to end the input. However, I keep pressing return but the process never moves on.

Comment: You didn't show the scenario where the command doesn't work, no Dockerfile, build command, or even the docker run command.

Comment: Are you sure it is the read command that "hangs"? Insert an `echo read finished` after the `read` to be sure.

Comment: I guess this not enough, add your `docker run` command please or `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: I've added more details. Thanks everyone. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post formatted text of commands, not pictures of commands. Pictures cannot be searched later, and cannot be copy and paste by someone trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next command:

```
docker run -it your_image
```

The root cause is you missed `-i`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) which make the container can't receive your input:

> --interactive , -i        Keep STDIN open even if not attached

And if you use `docker-compose`, remember to add next to compose file:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

`stdin_open` same to -i in docker run and `tty` same to -t.